# Configure Tomcat Memory (6 GB dedicated RAM for Apache Tomcat)

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat, memory, jvm

I am trying to extend the Memory dedicated to JVM. 
In my `calatlina.bat` configuration file. How can I dedicate atleast `6 GB of memory` to the Java Virtual Machine (JVM)? Below is my `catalina.bat file`.

```
@echo off
rem Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
rem contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
rem this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
rem The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
rem (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
rem the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
rem
rem     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
rem
rem Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
rem distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
rem See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
rem limitations under the License.

if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal
rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem Start/Stop Script for the CATALINA Server
rem
rem Environment Variable Prerequisites
rem
rem   CATALINA_HOME   May point at your Catalina "build" directory.
rem
rem   CATALINA_BASE   (Optional) Base directory for resolving dynamic portions
rem                   of a Catalina installation.  If not present, resolves to
rem                   the same directory that CATALINA_HOME points to.
rem
rem   CATALINA_OPTS   (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "start",
rem                   or "run" command is executed.
rem
rem   CATALINA_TMPDIR (Optional) Directory path location of temporary directory
rem                   the JVM should use (java.io.tmpdir).  Defaults to
rem                   %CATALINA_BASE%\temp.
rem
rem   JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
rem                   Required to run the with the "debug" argument.
rem
rem   JRE_HOME        Must point at your Java Runtime installation.
rem                   Defaults to JAVA_HOME if empty.
rem
rem   JAVA_OPTS       (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "start",
rem                   "stop", or "run" command is executed.
rem
rem   JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS (Optional) Lists of of semi-colon separated directories
rem                   containing some jars in order to allow replacement of APIs 
rem                   created outside of the JCP (i.e. DOM and SAX from W3C). 
rem                   It can also be used to update the XML parser implementation.
rem                   Defaults to $CATALINA_HOME/endorsed.
rem
rem   JPDA_TRANSPORT  (Optional) JPDA transport used when the "jpda start"
rem                   command is executed. The default is "dt_socket".
rem
rem   JPDA_ADDRESS    (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "jpda start"
rem                   command is executed. The default is 8000.
rem
rem   JPDA_SUSPEND    (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "jpda start"
rem                   command is executed. Specifies whether JVM should suspend
rem                   execution immediately after startup. Default is "n".
rem
rem   JPDA_OPTS       (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "jpda start"
rem                   command is executed. If used, JPDA_TRANSPORT, JPDA_ADDRESS,
rem                   and JPDA_SUSPEND are ignored. Thus, all required jpda
rem                   options MUST be specified. The default is:
rem
rem                   -agentlib:jdwp=transport=%JPDA_TRANSPORT%,
rem                       address=%JPDA_ADDRESS%,server=y,suspend=%JPDA_SUSPEND%
rem
rem   LOGGING_CONFIG  (Optional) Override Tomcat's logging config file
rem                   Example (all one line)
rem                   set LOGGING_CONFIG="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties"
rem
rem   LOGGING_MANAGER (Optional) Override Tomcat's logging manager 
rem                   Example (all one line)
rem                   set LOGGING_MANAGER="-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
rem
rem   TITLE           (Optional) Specify the title of Tomcat window. The default
rem                   TITLE is Tomcat if it's not specified.
rem                   Example (all one line)
rem                   set TITLE=Tomcat.Cluster#1.Server#1 [%DATE% %TIME%]
rem
rem
rem
rem $Id: catalina.bat 1146097 2011-07-13 15:25:05Z markt $
rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

rem Guess CATALINA_HOME if not defined
set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
if not "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "" goto gotHome
set "CATALINA_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%"
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat" goto okHome
cd ..
set "CATALINA_HOME=%cd%"
cd "%CURRENT_DIR%"
:gotHome
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat" goto okHome
echo The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
echo This environment variable is needed to run this program
goto end
:okHome

rem Copy CATALINA_BASE from CATALINA_HOME if not defined
if not "%CATALINA_BASE%" == "" goto gotBase
set "CATALINA_BASE=%CATALINA_HOME%"
:gotBase

rem Ensure that any user defined CLASSPATH variables are not used on startup,
rem but allow them to be specified in setenv.bat, in rare case when it is needed.
set CLASSPATH=

rem Get standard environment variables
if not exist "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat" goto checkSetenvHome
call "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat"
goto setenvDone
:checkSetenvHome
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setenv.bat" call "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setenv.bat"
:setenvDone

rem Get standard Java environment variables
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setclasspath.bat" goto okSetclasspath
echo Cannot find "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setclasspath.bat"
echo This file is needed to run this program
goto end
:okSetclasspath
set "BASEDIR=%CATALINA_HOME%"
call "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setclasspath.bat" %1
if errorlevel 1 goto end

if not "%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" == "" goto gotTmpdir
set "CATALINA_TMPDIR=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp"
:gotTmpdir

rem Add tomcat-juli.jar and bootstrap.jar to classpath
rem tomcat-juli.jar can be over-ridden per instance
rem Note that there are no quotes as we do not want to introduce random
rem quotes into the CLASSPATH
if "%CLASSPATH%" == "" goto emptyClasspath
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;"
:emptyClasspath
if "%CATALINA_BASE%" == "%CATALINA_HOME%" goto juliClasspathHome
if not exist "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar" goto juliClasspathHome
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\bootstrap.jar"
goto juliClasspathDone
:juliClasspathHome
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\bootstrap.jar"
:juliClasspathDone

if not "%LOGGING_CONFIG%" == "" goto noJuliConfig
set LOGGING_CONFIG=-Dnop
if not exist "%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties" goto noJuliConfig
set LOGGING_CONFIG=-Djava.util.logging.config.file="%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties"
:noJuliConfig
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%

if not "%LOGGING_MANAGER%" == "" goto noJuliManager
set LOGGING_MANAGER=-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
:noJuliManager
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%

rem ----- Execute The Requested Command ---------------------------------------

echo Using CATALINA_BASE:   "%CATALINA_BASE%"
echo Using CATALINA_HOME:   "%CATALINA_HOME%"
echo Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "%CATALINA_TMPDIR%"
if ""%1"" == ""debug"" goto use_jdk
echo Using JRE_HOME:        "%JRE_HOME%"
goto java_dir_displayed
:use_jdk
echo Using JAVA_HOME:       "%JAVA_HOME%"
:java_dir_displayed
echo Using CLASSPATH:       "%CLASSPATH%"

set _EXECJAVA=%_RUNJAVA%
set MAINCLASS=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
set ACTION=start
set SECURITY_POLICY_FILE=
set DEBUG_OPTS=
set JPDA=

if not ""%1"" == ""jpda"" goto noJpda
set JPDA=jpda
if not "%JPDA_TRANSPORT%" == "" goto gotJpdaTransport
set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
:gotJpdaTransport
if not "%JPDA_ADDRESS%" == "" goto gotJpdaAddress
set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
:gotJpdaAddress
if not "%JPDA_SUSPEND%" == "" goto gotJpdaSuspend
set JPDA_SUSPEND=n
:gotJpdaSuspend
if not "%JPDA_OPTS%" == "" goto gotJpdaOpts
set JPDA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=%JPDA_TRANSPORT%,address=%JPDA_ADDRESS%,server=y,suspend=%JPDA_SUSPEND%
:gotJpdaOpts
shift
:noJpda

if ""%1"" == ""debug"" goto doDebug
if ""%1"" == ""run"" goto doRun
if ""%1"" == ""start"" goto doStart
if ""%1"" == ""stop"" goto doStop
if ""%1"" == ""version"" goto doVersion

echo Usage:  catalina ( commands ... )
echo commands:
echo   debug             Start Catalina in a debugger
echo   debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager
echo   jpda start        Start Catalina under JPDA debugger
echo   run               Start Catalina in the current window
echo   run -security     Start in the current window with security manager
echo   start             Start Catalina in a separate window
echo   start -security   Start in a separate window with security manager
echo   stop              Stop Catalina
echo   version           What version of tomcat are you running?
goto end

:doDebug
shift
set _EXECJAVA=%_RUNJDB%
set DEBUG_OPTS=-sourcepath "%CATALINA_HOME%\..\..\java"
if not ""%1"" == ""-security"" goto execCmd
shift
echo Using Security Manager
set "SECURITY_POLICY_FILE=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\catalina.policy"
goto execCmd

:doRun
shift
if not ""%1"" == ""-security"" goto execCmd
shift
echo Using Security Manager
set "SECURITY_POLICY_FILE=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\catalina.policy"
goto execCmd

:doStart
shift
if not "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" goto noTitle
if "%TITLE%" == "" set TITLE=Tomcat
set _EXECJAVA=start "%TITLE%" %_RUNJAVA%
goto gotTitle
:noTitle
set _EXECJAVA=start %_RUNJAVA%
:gotTitle
if not ""%1"" == ""-security"" goto execCmd
shift
echo Using Security Manager
set "SECURITY_POLICY_FILE=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\catalina.policy"
goto execCmd

:doStop
shift
set ACTION=stop
set CATALINA_OPTS=
goto execCmd

:doVersion
%_EXECJAVA% -classpath "%CATALINA_HOME%\lib\catalina.jar" org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
goto end


:execCmd
rem Get remaining unshifted command line arguments and save them in the
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
:setArgs
if ""%1""=="""" goto doneSetArgs
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%CMD_LINE_ARGS% %1
shift
goto setArgs
:doneSetArgs

rem Execute Java with the applicable properties
if not "%JPDA%" == "" goto doJpda
if not "%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" == "" goto doSecurity
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
goto end
:doSecurity
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=="%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
goto end
:doJpda
if not "%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" == "" goto doSecurityJpda
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
goto end
:doSecurityJpda
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=="%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
goto end

:end
```

Comment: Better have a 64 bit OS.  32 bit JVMs can't have more than 1.5 GB.

Comment: I think it has to be done in JAVA_OPTS right?

Comment: Why don't you try? The description of both variables is exactly the same. I would guess that both will do.

Comment: How should I set that up? Means at what line, that's what the confusion I have. I read somewhere I can do it like this-  `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS - Xmx6144m
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"` But not sure where should I put this up in my catalina.bat file.

Comment: You could put it as the first line of the file if you don't want to define a global environment variable.